# How to limit the number of major versions to maintain on a document library list definition?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have 2 question here,

*Scenario:*
I have created a document library with my own list definition, having the default document library settings. There are quite number of document libraries created using my definition. Now I wanna change the version settings to limit number of major versions to 5.

I came across "MajorVersionLimit" List element property of Schema file, unfortunately this is available only for Content Migration schema alone. It didn't work for me.

*Question 1:*
**Is there any simple mechanism where I can enable such settings across my site collection?**

I know I can write piece of .NET code to change this. 
Question 2:
**If I do this, Will it break the list from its list definition?**

Thanks in advance.
~Yuva

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can set these values via the configuration file, but they are exposed on an SPList object.  So the trick is to find a way to capture when a new list is created from your template, and then set the fields ([SPList.MajorVersionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.majorversionlimit.aspx) and [SPList.appropriately](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.majorwithminorversionslimit.aspx)) appropriately.

I haven't tried this, but here's where I'd start.

1. In the [ListTemplate element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462947.aspx) configuration file, set the 'NewPage' property to a aspx page that should get displayed when the user clicks the 'create' button in the UI.
2. In the code behind for that page, create the list manually (using the OM) and set the properties.

There may be a better way, but I don't see it.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The **MajorVersionLimit** argument does work with **schema.xml**. Just remember to check the **Create a version each time you edit a file in this document library?** option.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way to modify existing webs is to write a small PowerShell script setting the spWeb.MajorVersionLimit, some thing like this:

```
#Set up connection

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$spSite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl) 

for($i=0; $i -lt $spSite.AllWebs.Count;$i++)

{

    $spWeb = $spSite.AllWebs[$i]
    for($j=0; $j -lt $spWeb.Lists.Count;$j++)
    {
        $aList = $spWeb.Lists[$j]
        if( $aList.Title -ceq "dokumenter") # case sensitive
        {
            if( $aList.EnableVersioning -eq $false)
            {
                $aList.EnableVersioning = $true
                $aList.MajorVersionLimit = 5;
                $aList.Update()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not true, you can set MajorVersionLimit through Scheme.xml (as List element attribute), it worked perfectly well for me . There is no support for these attributes through intellisense.

The solution was described on Doug "bobthebuilder" McCusker blog ( http://suguk.org/blogs/sharepointhack/archive/2008/01/14/7809.aspx )